# Paypal payment while I have my own shopping cart

Tags: java, paypal, payment-gateway

My question may look very simple but I could not find it in the paypal developer website.

I want to integrate an e-commerce website with any of paypal integration solutions (classic, rest, ...) that the payment process happens in the paypal website, in the other words user should enter his/her payment info in paypal pages but get back to my website after the payment.

**What I want**:

1. Having my own shopping cart
2. Having my place order (check out) page
3. Redirect the user to paypal page to do the payment
4. Get back to my website after payment process (successful or failure)

**What I DON'T want**:

1. calling smooth web services that user can not realize the payment is done via paypal

Can you provide any sample too? I prefer Java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out.

Paypal "Adaptive Payment" is what I am looking for. In my scenario the Application **owner** and the **receiver** would be the same. While the **sender** is the customer.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

**UPDATE:**

Sample code in Java can be found here: https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-java

Answer (score -1):

Without writing an applet that is embedded in your website, which would slow it down and require that your user is running Java on their device, there is no way to write it in java to the best of my knowledge. There is several free and paid services/software that you could use to accomplish this. The two that come to my mind first are WHMCS and BoxBilling.

If you are truly dedicated to writing your own application, try taking a look into PHP. PHP is a very powerful website back-end language that allows you to do virtually anything. You can find several tutorials on how to do this here (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/training/).

Hope I helped.

Comment: Why applet? Java is a Server side language too. Anything possible on PHP is possible on Java too. I did NOT get the point you were trying to say. Sorry.